# What does it mean for an object to be "finalizer-reachable" in Java?

Tags: java, finalizer

I am reading the Java 8 spec and I see this definition for finalizer-reachable:

```
A finalizer-reachable object can be reached from some finalizable object through some chain of references, but not from any live thread.
```

What would this look like in code? I don't have an intuition for what something like this would even look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example code below, when an instance of `Example` becomes unreachable, the object that `os` refers to will be finalizer-reachable.

```
  public class Example {

      private OutputStream os;

      public Example(OutputStream os) {
          this.os = 0s;
      }

      protected void finalize() {
          try {
              os.close();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              // ignore it
          }
     }
  }
```

However, if the `Example` instance was no longer eligible for finalization (e.g. because it had been finalized previously and then "resurrected" during finalization), then `os` would not be finalizer-reachable.

The "finalizer-reachable" state is about *specifying* that objects that *may be* referred to during finalization don't get deleted prematurely.  The specification does not state how this should be ensured. I imagine that it would not be possible for Java code (or even native code) to determine whether a specific object was is this state.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object Foo.  Foo is finalizable, and has no references in any variable in the program anymore.  Foo has a member Bar.  Bar references an object that is not referenced anywhere else.  The object Bar references is therefor finalizer-reachable.

Basically its an object that cannot be reached through the code anymore, but can be reached through another object that cannot be reached through the code.